# Animation is not looping

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

Im using Unity 5.3.4 and made some animation clips in the native animation panel of Unity, using keyframes.

In the Animator, I related those clips with transitions. I set "idle" as my entry clip and y checked "Loop Time" on it's properties. Nevertheless, when I hit play, the animation is not looping. It just play once and goes to the "jump" clip. Then it keeps rotation between "jump" and "hit".

Here's how things are done:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should control the animation behaviour with conditions for example if you want it to loop till something happened you should first add a parameter to use it for checking if something happened
 [image] 
then use it in conditions tab 
 for example you can make an bool parameter then use it in condition so when it was checked you will move to the next state till then it will just loop in the current state , if you put no condition so there is nothing stopping the state machine from going to the next state

[animation transitions](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Transition.html&ved=0ahUKEwjun7mIkJ_NAhVoEpoKHZrPDt4QFggbMAA&usg=AFQjCNEsEVY4yS7x8Vynz2YZaU4JGkoPgQ&sig2=zcLpVGe4pe3IY248KaKVPw) 
[Another tutorial](http://johnstejskal.com/wp/creating-2d-animations-from-sprite-sheets-in-unity3d-pt2/)

Comment: I still have no conditions added. So should stay on idle, don't it?

Comment: No , it will move to any state it can , you have to put conditions to stop it from going to other states , you have to close its way to other states